# Bootstrap last child css changes on page resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i have a 4 column row in bootstrap and i want to add a divider in between them. 
I've added this through the css and made it so .divider-right:last-child has no border. This is fine until you resize the page and it goes from a 4 column grid, to a two column grid.

```css
.divider-right {
  border-right:1px solid #dddddd;
}

.divider-right:last-child {
  border-right:transparent;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 divider-right">
   Content box in here
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 divider-right">
   Content box in here
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 divider-right">
   Content box in here
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 divider-right">
   Content box in here
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: so you don't want 2-column grid.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should handle removing the border as the viewport is reduced.

Add the appropriate [Pseudo Class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) to the relevant media query.

```css
.row div.divider-right {
  border-right: 1px solid #f00;
}
.row div.divider-right:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
@media(max-width:991px) {
  .row div.divider-right:nth-child(2n) {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
@media(max-width:767px) {
  .row div.divider-right {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 divider-right">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Content box in here1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 divider-right">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Content box in here2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 divider-right">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Content box in here3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 divider-right">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Content box in here4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: nice try dude though it's not working in some way by adding another few rows **https://jsfiddle.net/m6984whw/3/** please checkout

Comment: @Himesh Aadeshara Dude - Did you even read the question? "4 column row" is what it states and that's what the answer provides for. Feel free to answer your own question though.

Comment: Thanks Vanburenx, This worked for me and was what i was after

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to remove border of second element when it jumps to next div
try this code

```css
@media (max-width:991px) {
  .divider-right:nth-child(2n) {
    border-right: medium one;
  }
}
```